# Autochk cannot run due to an error caused by a recently installed software package

Tags: windows-7, chkdsk

When I reboot my Windows 7 machine, I get the error:

```
Autochk cannot run due to an error caused by a recently
installed software package
```

The only way I can get rid of it is to boot from the Windows install DVD, get into command prompt and run chkdsk.  Then when I reboot from the hard disk, there is no error, however, it eventually comes back.

Any ideas?

Comment: The relevant error message will actually be on _the line above_ that one.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this problem? I'm currently in the same situation.

Comment: @tftd, I eventually reinstalled Windows 7 and it no longer happens

Comment: I actually found a solution to this without reinstalling - get a "Windows 7 Recovery Disk", boot from it, in the options you can choose "Start Command Prompt". In the Command Prompt type `chkntfs C: /X` and then `chkdsk C: /F`. With `chkntfs` you exclude your drive from being checked on boot and with `chkdsk` you force your drive to be checked now. It fixed my problem so far. If this helps anybody else, upvote and I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), look for the AutoChk line and disable it by removing the checkmark,
have caution when you decide to remove other things to optimize your boot as you could brick your OS.

It's safe to disable AutoChk, but you should scan sometimes so you don't run into unexpected problems.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to prevent autochk from running with Chkntfs ant the /x

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771787(WS.10).aspx

but the bigger issue is why is your drive being flagged as dirty? Is the drive starting to die maybe. try running some HDD diagnostics on it. like WD lifeguard or the Seagate equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i had this problem too... it is related to a corrupted usb***.sys file.

Check your recently installed software first and hardware... memory, hdd...

FIX:  Boot from the Windows install DVD, get into command prompt and run "chkdsk X: /F" where X is the driver you have your system on.

Comment: That does solve the problem temporarily but then it comes back again eventually.

Comment: If the usb**.sys is a file from Microsoft, then you can fix it with `sfc /scannow` when you have booted the system and go into the console. If it is not, then you should update the related drivers to the latest versions. @JoelFan: Please note that your problem could be unrelated with the mentioned file.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue on a client's PC. In this specific case the machine would randomly restart without any warning, and attempting to run Autochk at startup would fail with the same "**Autochk cannot run due to an error caused by a recently installed software package**" error.

Once the option to automatically restart following a crash was disabled it became clear that a file called **HMFAxCoreXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.sys** was causing the system halt. Googling this file revealed it to be a component of the **Hide My Folders** application. The application itself could not be removed via the usual add and remove programs function - it looked like someone else had made a hamfisted attempt at removing it, breaking it in the process.

Renaming HMFAxCoreXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.sys then restarting the system instantly fixed the unexpected restarts and restored Autochk functionality at startup.

Obviously this is an old thread but hopefully this may be of use to someone in a similar situation.