# Why does my Windows 7 cannot fix hard drive and normally boot as usual?

Tags: windows-7, bad-sectors

In recovery mode it shows: cannot run autochk cause of last installled software.

When i choose normal booting it just freeze after  scanning hard drive and trying do fix it.

In linux i disk manager  i have: Warning the disk has a bad sector..... we sugest run chkdsk /f /r on windows and rebbot.

So i plugged CD of windows, went to recovery mode/ advenced/console and started "chkdsk /f /r"

Scanned all drives but its not showing any signs of bad sectors...

Comment: [Similar Question](http://superuser.com/questions/145611/autochk-cannot-run-due-to-an-error-caused-by-a-recently-installed-software-packa)

Answer (score 0):

When you have not the appropriate access (admin) you get this message.
normally you should be able to run a chkdsk /f in save mode